# Select into existing table where ID is in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, select, copy

I have one table containing ~35k `ID`s (`TableC`), one table that features multiple columns (`TableA`), amongst others the `ID` from the before mentioned table and a third empty table, featuring the same columns as the second table (`TableB`).

Now I'm required to copy every entry from `TableA` to `TableB` where the `ID` of `TableA` is in `TableC`. I came up with this query:

```
SELECT * INTO TableB
FROM TableA
WHERE ID IN
(SELECT ID FROM TableC)
```

But this leads to the error `There is already an object named 'TableB' in the database.`.. I'm not allowed to delete and re-create `TableB` for this.

Working on Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition v9.00.3042.00, i.e. SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2

How can I copy  every entry from `TableA` to `TableB` where the `ID` of `TableA` is in `TableC`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `SELECT ... INTO` syntax is only for new tables. 
I think you want:

```
INSERT dbo.TableB ( <column list> )
SELECT <column list>
FROM dbo.TableA
WHERE ID IN 
  (
    SELECT ID
    FROM dbo.TableC
  ) ;
```